# need a timer for my C# morse converter

Tags: c#, timer

I'm trying to develop an application to convert text to morse code and vice versa. I just managed to do the first phase completely which means when you type a character you will see the encoded type of that character.
but in the second phase I got some problem:
here is my code:(hint:sw=first stopwatch,flagsw=second stopwatch,datas=dataset,dbc=databaseconverter,listofcode=string of '.' and '-')

```
private void txtletters_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    txtletters.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    sw.Start();
    if (flagsw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 400)
    {
        datas = dbc.srchfortext(listofcode);
        lbltext.DataBindings.Clear();
        lbltext.DataBindings.Add("text", datas, "t.letter");
        txtletters.Text += lbltext.Text;
        listofcode = "";
    }
    flagsw.Reset();
}

private void txtletters_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    txtletters.BackColor = Color.White;
    sw.Stop();
    if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 250)
        listofcode += ".";
    else
        listofcode += "-";
    sw.Reset();
    flagsw.Start();
}
```

I just managed to do the work somehow but as the code shown:
when you press any key first timer will start and first timer determine if it is . or -
when you release it second timer will start (with that timer I want to know if the string of '.','-' should be closed and send to database to return the specified character...the problem in here is that the application won't end the timer and return the char unless I preform a keydown again and that means I'm not gonna see the char i typed unless I press another key(just don't tell me it's because that the second timer is in keydown, I had to do that cause I didn't have any other choice...But at least I know the Idea but don't know how to implement it...I just need somebody to help me implement it...)
I need that second timer works in background when a keydown occurred it will reset and when a keyup occurred(means that key released)it will start again. whenever second timer(flagsw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 400)got bigger than that time it will do the job and clear the string for next use.

Comment: You might want to look into timers (eg https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). They will fire off some code after a certain amount of time which sounds like it could be what you are after. So you might set a 2 second timer, reset the timer every time you get a dot or a dash and after 2 seconds of not being reset it will assume you are done and run whatever code you need to check what your dots and dashes translate to.

Comment: You can only decode Morse correctly when you *also* measure the amount of time the key is up.  And detect when that time it is long enough to end a symbol, only then can you convert the dah-dits to a character.  You have corner cases for the very first and the very last time you press a key.  The first keydown does not give you a pause time, handle that with a *bool*.  The last keyup does not give you an event to end the pause time measurement, handle that with a Timer from the toolbox.

Comment: @Chris , Much appreciate it Chris...with your idea I just managed to implement something better than that previous timer...Now my code uses a global timer...just one more thing...that timer will elapse every 2 sec but there is a little problem if its 0 sec and i type something it will works correctly but if it is on for example 1.5 sec it will separately decode my dot-dash...any solution??

Answer (score -1):

First I have to thanks to Chris...with your answer I got the idea and found the way...
It's now fully implemented and works here is my code if anybody else wants to use...(it's just the decoder part of the morse project)

```
namespace Morse_Code
{
    public partial class frmdecdotmode : Form
    {
        Boolean flag_isdown = false;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        Timer morse_timer = new Timer();
        string listofcode;
        DataSet datas = new DataSet();
        DataBaseController dbc = new DataBaseController();
        public frmdecdotmode()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmdecdotmode_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            MainMenu mm = new MainMenu();
            mm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void txtletters_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            flag_isdown = true;
            txtletters.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            sw.Start();
            morse_timer.Stop();
        }

        private void txtletters_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            flag_isdown = false;
            txtletters.BackColor = Color.White;
            sw.Stop();
            if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 250)
                listofcode += ".";
            else
                listofcode += "-";
            sw.Reset();
            morse_timer.Start();
        }

        private void frmdecdotmode_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            morse_timer.Interval = 1000;
            morse_timer.Enabled = true;
            morse_timer.Tick += morse_timer_Tick;
        }
        private void morse_timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (flag_isdown == false && listofcode != null)
            {
                datas = dbc.srchfortext(listofcode);
                lbltext.DataBindings.Clear();
                lbltext.DataBindings.Add("text", datas, "t.letter");
                txtletters.Text += lbltext.Text;
                listofcode = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to every body who helped me do this...
Ya Ali(a.s)